# No Add New Entry button

Tags: error

I'm just a beginner in Craft CMS but i'm wondering why there's no Add New Entry button in my dashboard. What should be the problem with it?

Comment: Has there been any update/solution on this ?
We are having the same issue after updating from 3.0.35 to 3.1.34.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a **Quick Post** widget that allows you to create entries from the Dashboard page of the Control Panel.

A **New Entry** button is available from the entries index pages located at the top right, e.g. http://
example.com/admin/entries/news